# Unable to recreate object from var_exported data (in PHP)

Tags: php, serialization, deserialization

A script running on on our live server sends out data from the following line:

```
$log_output .= '<br>'.__LINE__.'<br>recordings_data='.var_export($recordings_data,TRUE);
```

Which looks like this:

> recordings_data=stdClass::__set_state(array( 'RecordingLongResponse'
>   => array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(...), 1 => stdClass::__set_state(), 2 => stdClass::__set_state(), 3 =>
>   stdClass::__set_state(array( 'roomStartDate' => '1321977120000',
>   'roomEndDate' => '1321977120000', 'recordingURL' => 'serverURL1',
>   'secureSignOn' => false, 'recordingId' => '1287268130290',
>   'creationDate' => '1321977120000', 'recordingSize' => '6765975',
>   'roomName' => 'Stakeholder Analysis', 'sessionId' => '1287268130229',
>   )), ...), ))

I'm not sure how to 'recreate' the object. I tried unserializing it:

```
 $recording_data_ser= file_get_contents('elm-ser-data.txt'); // where I've saved everything after the '='
 $recording_data = unserialize($recording_data_ser);
```

Answer (score 4):

`serialize()` and `unserialize()` are the generally accepted methods for dumping/loading PHP objects.  You can also do it with `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`.  Is there a reason you want to use `var_export()`?

Edit: you can only `unserialize()` the result of `serialize()` - `var_dump()` is in a completely different format and isn't designed for importing unless you use `eval()`.

For example:

```
$arr = array('foo' => 'bar');

var_export($arr);
#=> array (
#=>  'foo' => 'bar',
#=> )

echo serialize($arr);
#=> a:1:{s:3:"foo";s:3:"bar";}

echo json_encode($arr);
#=> {"foo":"bar"}
```

Once you have the serialized data (via `serialize()` or `json_encode()`), you can use the opposite method (`unserialize()` or `json_decode()`, respectively) to recreate the object again.

Comment: +1. There you go. I commented earlier, because I thought it would be just another BOM issue, but I just saw what the OP is doing. :)

Answer (score 3):

var_export() is intended to dump a data structure to a file. You then have to `eval()` or `include()` or `require()` that file. the serialize() format is completely different from var_export.

var_export produces valid PHP code to define a data structure, as if you'd written out the array/object definition yourself. serialize/unserialize write out in a completely different format, and they're not interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `var_export()` on an instance of `stdClass`, it attempts to export it using `::__set_state()`, which, for some reason, is not implemented in `stdClass`.

However, casting an associative array to an object usually produces the same effect (at least, it does in my case). So I wrote an `improved_var_export()` function to convert instances of `stdClass` to `(object) array ()` calls. If you choose to export objects of any other class, I'd advise you to implement `::__set_state()` in those classes.

```
<?php
/**
 * An implementation of var_export() that is compatible with instances
 * of stdClass.
 * @param mixed $variable The variable you want to export
 * @param bool $return If used and set to true, improved_var_export()
 *     will return the variable representation instead of outputting it.
 * @return mixed|null Returns the variable representation when the
 *     return parameter is used and evaluates to TRUE. Otherwise, this
 *     function will return NULL.
 */
function improved_var_export ($variable, $return = false) {
    if ($variable instanceof stdClass) {
        $result = '(object) '.improved_var_export(get_object_vars($variable), true);
    } else if (is_array($variable)) {
        $array = array ();
        foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
            $array[] = var_export($key, true).' => '.improved_var_export($value, true);
        }
        $result = 'array ('.implode(', ', $array).')';
    } else {
        $result = var_export($variable, true);
    }

    if (!$return) {
        print $result;
        return null;
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}

// Example usage:
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->test = 'abc';
$obj->other = 6.2;
$obj->arr = array (1, 2, 3);

improved_var_export((object) array (
    'prop1' => true,
    'prop2' => $obj,
    'assocArray' => array (
        'apple' => 'good',
        'orange' => 'great'
    )
));

/* Output:
(object) array ('prop1' => true, 'prop2' => (object) array ('test' => 'abc', 'other' => 6.2, 'arr' => array (0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3)), 'assocArray' => array ('apple' => 'good', 'orange' => 'great'))
*/

// Example implementation in context of OP
$export = improved_var_export($data, true);
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/data.php', '<'.'?php return '.$export.'; ?'.'>');

// "Unserialization" (evaluation)
$import = include dirname(__FILE__).'/data.php';
?>
```